# Asking about India books in math

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I found a very good book for basic functional analysis and the author was from India. The book is a functional analysis by Sharma and Vasishtha. I was told there are many very good math books in India. I am nicely asking anyone who knows some books to share that with me.  I am most interested in real analysis, calculus, topology, set theory, abstract algebra, and complex analysis. I do not mind if the book is an introduction or an advanced book.   Any idea will be appreciated greatly

Comment: Why are you so interested in specifying Indian authors? Also, that is quite a range of topics!

Comment: Notes on Functional Analysis
(Book by Rajendra Bhatia ) is  a good one.

Comment: Real analysis by Sharma.

Comment: Hypothetically, if I was living in India, and I did not have access to a university library in India, or a Math professor in India, I would talk to the librarian at a local library in India.  I would ask the librarian to try to arrange for me to communicate with a Math professor in India.  Alternatively, I would approach a high school Math teacher, and try that communication channel.

Comment: Topology of Metric Spaces
Book by S. KUMARESAN

Comment: **Shoot for the moon. Even if you miss, you'll land among the stars." - Les Brown**

Comment: Strat with Rudin, Dummit-Foote, Munkres, Lang, Rajendra bhatiya, Conway, Axler...

Comment: @LostinSpace, I think I know most of them except the last one, Axler. What is this book ?